# WooCommerce wrong path to product image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build eCommerce with Wordpress and WooCommerce and got a problem. In Friday everything worked and yesterday and today I launch a project and it cannot display image for the product. I mean when it's product list, I can see image, but when I get into a single product area, the image is not displayed. What's weird, when I hover on the not displayed image, zoom works correctly and I can see zoomed image...

I'm using localhost and PHP server to develop the project. PHP log shows that kind of error

> [404] /wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image-600x848.jpg - No such file or
>   directory

right after that shows

> [200] /wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image.jpg

How to fix it and why suddenly it takes an image with a different dimension?

Comment: Please share your site url.

Comment: As I said i develop it locally so site Address URL is http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I was able to fix it. While choosing picture, I just had to click on "edit image" and manually change its dimensions (actually it didn't need to be this 600x848), it just had to be different than original one. And magically it works again.